# listRef.listAll() function is undefined (react-native-firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I am trying to get the list of images in a directory from firebase storage.

Example I want to get all image in **users/userid/images**, but it does not work and popup an error which the function is undefined.

```
const listRef = storageRef.child('users/userid/images');
listRef.listAll().then(res=>{
  res.items.forEach(itemRef=>{
    // console.log(itemRef);
  });
}).catch(e =>{});
```

Comment: are you solve it?

Comment: Yeah I will as answer please, check it and vt it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to list files in a storage bucket wasn't added until [version 6.1.0 of the JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_610_-_may_28_2019).  So make sure your SDK is up to date.

Comment: Hi thank you, I am using `react-native-firebase v 5.5.3` I dont know this version supports `v6.1` or no

Comment: You might want to raise an issue with the repo maintainer of any wrapper SDK that you use.

Answer (score 0):

And now we can do it as well, thnk you from `react-native-firebase` team.

```
const reference = storage().ref('images');

const getListOfImages = async (){
   const res = await reference.child('profileimages').list();
   return await Promise.all(res.items.map(i => i.getDownloadURL()));
}
```